# The «prefix» «infix» «suffix» pepper flakes

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

> I got what I desired; food served at my expense
> Split up as affixes, the following makes sense

> My «prefix» is fickle; it’s not scared of snakes
> The «prefix» «infix» «suffix» pepper flakes

*What* am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you are

> CATERED.

I got what I desired; food served at my expense

> The definition of catered.

Split up as affixes, the following makes sense

My «prefix» is fickle; it’s not scared of snakes

> My CAT is fickle; it’s not scared of snakes

The «prefix» «infix» «suffix» pepper flakes

> The CAT ATE RED pepper flakes

Comment: rot13(Pngf nera'g nsenvq bs fanxrf?  Uhaqerqf bs LbhGhor ivqrbf vaibyivat phphzoref ort gb qvssre...)

Comment: Maybe some are, but Ebe’s is definitely NOT scared of snakes 